# Piping output simultaneously while asking for user input

Tags: linux, python-2.7, shell, console

I have a python script where from time to time user is required to provide some input. Script also prints various output to the console. If I redirect output to the file, for example

```
python script.py > log_file
```

then no questions asking for input will be displayed. How can I achieve that output is simultaneously printed to the console and file. I tried

```
python script.py | tee log_file
```

but this did not work well (messages asking user to provide input were not shown).

Comment: Write the prompts to `stderr` or `/dev/tty`.

Comment: so how should I run the script? Which command to use?

Comment: You need to change the script.

Comment: `tty = open('/dev/tty', 'w'); write(tty, 'Enter a name:'); name = input()`

Comment: Instead of `name = input('Enter a name:')`